# Issues with angular-filter and opening accordion on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-filters

Since adding angular-filter the accordion is not opening on page load. I guess it's something to do with the code `is-open="group.isOpen"` and `group` not being valid in that instance anymore?, cause the code's now using `key, value`? What am I doing wrong?

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AAdm72sPkGYsrPFDt5RQ?p=preview) of the issue.

** edit: (( And, as requested in the comments, [here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rKwbjlEta4rzJIyVUFjt?p=preview) of the accordion opening on page load before adding angular-filter  )).

here's the html:

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">

      <accordion-group is-open="group.isOpen" ng-repeat="(key, value) in groups | groupBy: 'title'">
        <accordion-heading><i class="glyphicon-plus"></i> {{ key }}
          <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !group.isOpen}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
       <p ng-repeat="group in value"> {{ group.content }}</p>
        <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="group in value">

        {{ group.list }}
      </li>
    </ul>

      </accordion-group>

    </accordion>
  </div>
```

Here's the js:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
angular.module('app').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      content: 'content 1',
      isOpen: true,
      list: 'item0a'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      content: 'Content 2',
      list: 'item0b' 
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      content: 'Content 3',
      list: 'item0c' 
    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      content: 'content 4',
      list: 'item0d' 
    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      content: 'content 5',
      list: 'item0e' 
    },
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      list: 'item1a'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      list: 'item2a'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      list: 'item3a'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      list: 'item1b'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      list: 'item2b'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      list: 'item1c'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      list: 'item2c'
    },    
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      list: 'item1d'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      list: 'item1e'
    }
  ];
});
```

Comment: To solve this we'd have to understand how this specific accordion library works. You said before you had an example where this worked? You should post that. Googling "bootstrap group is-open" also told me that http://victorleungtw.com/angular-ui-bootstrap/ , that might work.

Comment: See edit above. Due to using the chevrons on the right to denote an open and closed accordion group, my original working version has a work around of the more common simpler implementations. `group.isOpen` is also being used to change the chevron direction so I'm not sure that example will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you have a specific reason for your object structure, but something like

```
{
  title: 'title 1',
  content: 'content 1',
  isOpen: true,
  list: ['item1a',
    'item2a',
    'item3a']
}
```

makes more sense to me. Now you basically don't need to change the actual view much at all, other than adding the list.

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
        {{ item }}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LBNQ2ukERMEzH3gKQ4M6?p=preview

Comment: Thanks this is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, if an object should belong to another object it's better to make it a child of that object, either through a reference or directly. Much easier to do manipulation then (as you noticed). Also you had list items (child object) in the same object level as the groups (parents), which there's also no reason to. You could have kept them as their own arrays (which would make this trickier but could for example facilitate shared lists), but they should still have been separate properties in your controller.